# How to remove unwanted projects from STS Boot Dashboard

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven-2, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Eclipse STS 3.8.1

**Is there anyway to remove apps from the Boot Dashboard?**

**Reason for asking** (Similar to my real world application/s):
I have multiple Spring Boot applications, some of which use a shared library.  In this library I have some common configuration:  Eg:  Setup RestTemplate/s with Ribbon (@LoadBalancer)...

On order to have access to the @Configuration and @Bean annotations I include the below dependancy into my libraries pom:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem is now my library is displayed in the Boot Dashboard with my applications even though it is not a Boot Application.

This is rather annoying as it clutters the dashboard, how can I remove this?

---

Just to expand on my above example:
I'm using a multi-module maven project with multiple applications and libs under the same parent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to the Preferences -> Spring -> Boot and configure the projects to be excluded from the boot dashboard by default. Just put the name of the project in that text field.

Comment: Use `|` separator for multiple projects. eg : `Project-A|Project-B`  etc;

Comment: and it is a regexp: if you have a collection of modules/projects with common parts in the name, you can use a regex: I used eg "Project-A|Project-B|<root>.*" and it works